# Boost 1.64 build error on solaris

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, g++, solaris

```
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/include/limits.h:12:0,
                 from /export/home/user/gcc-6.2.0.bin/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/6.2.0/include-fixed/limits.h:168,
                 from /export/home/user/gcc-6.2.0.bin/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/6.2.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /export/home/user/gcc-6.2.0.bin/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/6.2.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from libs/log/src/attribute_set.cpp:16:
/export/home/user/gcc-6.2.0.bin/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/6.2.0/include-fixed/sys/feature_tests.h:363:2: error: #error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications       and pre-2001 POSIX applications"
 #error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications \
  ^~~~~

"g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -march=i686 -pthreads -m32 -fno-strict-aliasing -ftemplate-depth-1024 -fvisibility=hidden -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_ATOMIC_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_CHRONO_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_LOG_BUILDING_THE_LIB=1 -DBOOST_LOG_USE_AVX2 -DBOOST_LOG_USE_SSSE3 -DBOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_DEBUG_OUTPUT -DBOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_EVENT_LOG -DBOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_IPC -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_BUILD_LIB=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_DONT_USE_CHRONO=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_POSIX -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D__EXTENSIONS__ -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS  -I"." -I"libs/log/src" -c -o "bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/attribute_set.o" "libs/log/src/attribute_set.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/attribute_set.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/attribute_value_set.o
<command-line>:0:0: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined
<built-in>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/include/limits.h:12:0,
                 from /export/home/user/gcc-6.2.0.bin/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/6.2.0/include-fixed/limits.h:168,
                 from /export/home/user/gcc-6.2.0.bin/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/6.2.0/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /export/home/user/gcc-6.2.0.bin/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/6.2.0/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from libs/log/src/attribute_value_set.cpp:16:
/export/home/user/gcc-6.2.0.bin/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/6.2.0/include-fixed/sys/feature_tests.h:363:2: error: #error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications       and pre-2001 POSIX applications"
 #error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications \
  ^~~~~

"g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -march=i686 -pthreads -m32 -fno-strict-aliasing -ftemplate-depth-1024 -fvisibility=hidden -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_ATOMIC_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_CHRONO_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_LOG_BUILDING_THE_LIB=1 -DBOOST_LOG_USE_AVX2 -DBOOST_LOG_USE_SSSE3 -DBOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_DEBUG_OUTPUT -DBOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_EVENT_LOG -DBOOST_LOG_WITHOUT_IPC -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_BUILD_LIB=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_DONT_USE_CHRONO=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_POSIX -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D__EXTENSIONS__ -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS  -I"." -I"libs/log/src" -c -o "bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/attribute_value_set.o" "libs/log/src/attribute_value_set.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/attribute_value_set.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/link-static/threading-multi/code_conversion.o
<command-line>:0:0: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined




...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/threading-multi>libboost_log.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/threading-multi>attribute_name.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_log.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/threading-multi>libboost_log.so.1.64.0...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_log.so for lack of <pstage/lib>libboost_log.so.1.64.0...
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/config.hpp:33,
                 from ./boost/log/detail/setup_config.hpp:20,
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/threading-multi>libboost_log_setup.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/threading-multi>setup/parser_utils.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_log_setup.so.1.64.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/log/build/gcc-6.2.0/release/threading-multi>libboost_log_setup.so.1.64.0...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_log_setup.so for lack of <pstage/lib>libboost_log_setup.so.1.64.0...
```

There are some error logs in building Boost C ++ Libraries 1.64 with GCC 6.2 version . What's the problem?
It is one of the many error logs.

```
$b2
```

This occurred during execution of the above command. Logs and python libraries have had intensive error logs.

I wonder why this error occurred.

- **Build environment**
- Oracle Solaris 11.2 x86 23 June 2014
- GCC 6.2
- **Build target**
- Boost C ++ Libraries 1.64

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're hitting this chunk of standards checking in feature_test.h:

```
#if defined(_STDC_C99) && (defined(__XOPEN_OR_POSIX) && !defined(_XPG6))
#error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications \
        and pre-2001 POSIX applications"
#elif !defined(_STDC_C99) && \
        (defined(__XOPEN_OR_POSIX) && defined(_XPG6))
#error "Compiler or options invalid; UNIX 03 and POSIX.1-2001 applications \
        require the use of c99"
#endif
```

and it is the first #error that is triggering.

The UNIX standards have many (confusing) names, POSIX, Xopen, IEEE XPG, SUS. Before the Single Unix Standard 3 (SUSv3) C90 was used. SUSv3 and after use C99. g++ 6.2, which defaults to C++14 for C++ is also setting the c11 flags (`#define __STDC_VERSION__ 201112L`)

The upshot of all this is that you probably need to set the _XPG6 macro. Normally you don't do this directly, you should be setting _XOPEN_SOURCE to 600, and I see that it is set to 500 in your command line.

Comment: This does appear to be a Boost bug. [Per the comments in `sys/feature_tests.h`](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/feature_tests.h#388):  "It is invalid to compile an XPG3, XPG4, XPG4v2, or XPG5 application using c99. ..."  [A Google search for "c99 and xpg5"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c99+and+xpg5) yields a number of results - and the fix seems to be to properly define `_XOPEN_SOURCE=600`.  It'd be nice to find the actual POSIX reference(s) for the behavior.

Comment: It's more a case of Solaris headers being broken. The headers check for the C standard version, but the C++ compiler does not have to define any C version macros. Formally, that makes the system headers incompatible with C++. Next is the absolutely unreasonable limitation that `_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` is incompatible with C99. One is forced to either C89+`_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` or C99+`_XOPEN_SOURCE=600`. IMO, it is Solaris headers that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @AndreySemashev *It's more a case of Solaris headers being broken. The headers check for the C standard version, but the C++ compiler does not have to define any C version macros.*  You didn't read the header files. http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/feature_tests.h#150 The C version macro is getting defined to C99 or higher by GCC.  Sounds like a GCC issue, it not a Boost issue.

Comment: My point is that the C++ standard does not define `__STDC_VERSION__`, which is a C language macro, see [cpp.predefined]/2. A conforming compiler is not required to define it or can define it to any value it wants. Checking for it in system headers means incompatibility with C++.

Comment: @AndreySemashev *Checking for it in system headers means incompatibility with C++* Then if the compiler wishes to be POSIX-compliant, it best not define C99 or later macros when compiling with `_XOPEN_SOURCE` less than 600 or `_XPG5` or less.  Again, a *compiler* problem.  The headers are merely enforcing POSIX compliance.

Comment: I don't think I've seen where POSIX prohibits C89 with `_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` or C99 with `_XOPEN_SOURCE=500`. Do you have a reference? If there is such limitation in POSIX then, IMO, it is POSIX that needs to be fixed and then the Solaris headers. Because that limitation doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AndreySemashev POSIX is a *standard*, it doesn't need to be fixed.  Just because GCC apparently has chosen not to abide by that standard doesn't make that standard wrong. There are likely very good reasons for not allowing C99 mode for XPG 5 and earlier.  Just because you're used to using GCC doesn't make GCC always correct.  Did you fail to follow the Google search I found where *numerous* different applications had problems with XPG5 or earlier and C99?  The fix was invariably to not try using C99 with XPG5 or earlier.  Here it is again:  https://www.google.com/search?q=c99+and+xpg5

Comment: *POSIX is a standard, it doesn't need to be fixed.* Not true. Standards can have bugs, too. But I have not yet found where POSIX mandates those requirements, so for now I question whether they actually exist. *Just because you're used to using GCC doesn't make GCC always correct.* It's not about me being a fan of gcc or not. It has its problems, but in this case I do not see how it is the culprit.

Comment: *Did you fail to follow the Google search* The search results show 4 problem reports specifically about Solaris, 1 for IRIX and 1 for FreeBSD. To me, this clearly indicates that Solaris is a white crow in the UNIX world rather than a rule, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to infer from that.

Comment: The spec is quite clear. "UNIX 03
Category: Operating System and Languages [XY]

The UNIX 03 Product Standard is the mark for systems conforming to Version 3 of the Single UNIX Specification. It is a significantly enhanced version of the UNIX 98 Product Standard. The mandatory enhancements include alignment with ISO/IEC 9989:1999 C Programming Language, IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 and ISO/IEC 9945:2002. " - from https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/xym0.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. That doesn't prohibit using newer versions of the C language. Or the C++ language. Basically, the spec requires a C99 compiler to be present, but it doesn't say there must not be a C89 compiler, a C11 compiler or a C++ compiler on a conforming system.

Comment: Don't be obtuse. Do you really believe that a C99 compiler is mandated, and then they provide APIs that can be compiled with C89? As for forwards compatibility, obviously standards writers have no crystal ball and can't specify behaviour with future versions of other standards. If there are no backwards compatibility issues between C99 and C11 then there should be no issue, but a standard like SUSv3 won't have been able to specify anything.

Comment: *Do you really believe that a C99 compiler is mandated, and then they provide APIs that can be compiled with C89?* Why not? 90% of the API has been carried over from the previous standard, which worked fine with C89. Why on earth must it break in the new one? And I'm sure most of the new APIs don't require anything beyond C89 either.

Comment: *As for forwards compatibility, obviously standards writers have no crystal ball and can't specify behaviour with future versions of other standards.* Crystal ball is not required, and as far as I can see the standard writers rightfully did not try to guess. Simply specify the required parts of the system and do not preclude other parts, such as other compilers. That's it, everyone's happy. Why would Solaris devs try to prevent that is beyond me.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Read what are labelled "QUIET CHANGES" in the [C99 Rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf)  You'll note that C99 **is not backwards compatible with C89**.  Preprocessor arithmetic changed. Digraphs changed. Scope rules changed. Unsigned preserving rules changed. Floating-point math changed. External symbol linkage changed. Integer constant types changed. Character constants changed. Escape sequences changed. Comments changed. Assignment operators changed. POSIX standards that predate the C99 standard **are not compatible** with C99.

Comment: Sure, there are breaking changes in C99. But, as the referenced document states, many of these changes were made to follow the existing practice and expectations. It is expected that little to no code is affected by them. I hate to repeat myself, but the previously available POSIX APIs were implemented in C89 and carried over to the new standard with no changes. I don't have Solaris locally, but I'm sure you'll find little or no places where XPG5 APIs need to be conditioned on the C version. Thus the distinction is not warranted - neither by POSIX nor by practice.

Comment: This is not how standards bodies like IEEE work. They have a current set of standards and all older standards are deprecated. There's no "well it's sort of 99% backwards compatible". It may have escaped your attention, but Solaris _is_ SUSv3 compliant whilst most Linix distros aren't. This doc http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5175/standards-5/index.html in the Compilation section seems to set out fairly strict requirements. Of course, if you're not happy with the Open Group/IEEE standards, you can join them and try to get them changed.

Comment: @AndreySemashev If Linux is sufficient for you - where `fork()` doesn't meet POSIX async-signal-safe requirements and `pwrite()` is broken - that's fine for you.  Other people and operating systems have higher standards.  There are reasons why you can drive a Solaris server into hard swapping for hours and it comes back fine, but if you do the same to a Linux box it pretty much needs to be rebooted *a la* Windows.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Again, the document you linked does not prohibit multiple different C compilers on the system. OTOH, it confirms my previous statement that the headers are incompatible with C++: *C++ bindings are not defined for POSIX or X/Open CAE, so specifying feature test macros such as _POSIX_SOURCE, _POSIX_C_SOURCE, and _XOPEN_SOURCE can result in compilation errors due to conflicting requirements of standard C++ and those specifications.* So here you go, the correct answer to the original question is that C++ + POSIX is not supported on Solaris.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Regarding standardization, while I'm not a member of Open Group/IEEE committees, I do realize that the world does not switch immediately to a new revision of a standard as soon as it is published. I also realize that no standard covers everything. I'm sure there are people much smarter than me in the committee and that they realize all that as well. What follows from that is that POSIX must (and AFAICS does) allow being used from languages other than C99. The problem is specific to Solaris; other systems (yes, including Linux) have no problem with POSIX with C++ or C other than 99.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't see how your comment is relevant.

Comment: @AndreySemashev To summarize, your opinion of a standard that you haven't even read is that other OSes that do conform to the standard should be like Linux which doesn't conform. I don't see how this is going to help anyone, the OP included.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I didn't say that. I said that this is a Solaris specific problem, not POSIX. And I think people would benefit from a system that can actually be used from C++, regardless of how conforming you claim it to be.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Are you trolling? You haven't read the standards, you don't use Solaris yet you seem perfectly ready to give your opinion. The list of certified UNIX systems can be found here https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/ .  With C++ on Solaris, if the compiler claims C89 compatibility (or makes no claims) then it will work if you use XOPEN 500 or less. If the compiler claims C99 or later compatibility then it will work if you use XOPEN 600 or later.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Yes, I haven't read POSIX in full - because I have other things to do with my time. I do read it on demand though and I have experience working with different systems, including Solaris BTW. But assuming you have read it, you should be able to present a reference supporting your point. You haven't so far, which means either there is none or you are the same kind of cheap-talk as apparently I am. I think we can stop the discussion now and agree to disagree.

Answer (score -1):

As was discovered in the discussion following the **Paul Floyd**'s answer, Solaris headers are incompatible with C++, which results in the errors you're seeing.

This can be worked around by modifying Boost.Log sources, libs/log/build/Jamfile.v2, line 256. Change it from this:

```
<target-os>solaris:<define>_XOPEN_SOURCE=500
```

to this:

```
<target-os>solaris:<define>_XOPEN_SOURCE=600
```

(I stripped the comment for brevity).

In Boost 1.65 the library should try to work around the problem automatically, so this modification should not be needed.